# Error in getting folder size for the Pictures folder in android

Tags: java, android, file, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I published my new application in the play store and a user told me that when he open a fragment in the application, the app crashes.. I have the logCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dd.androreboot.devicefragment.getFolderSize(devicefragment.java:216)
at com.dd.androreboot.devicefragment.onCreateView(devicefragment.java:95)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and at the line 95 i have this

```
// Pictures
        File pictures = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Pictures/");
        float picturesize=getFolderSize(pictures)/(1024f*1024f);
```

He has a `Lg optimus L9 P760` so i think that the problem is that phone hasn't got the Picture folder or it's not in that path so the application crash.. Could be this the problem?

Comment: What's on line 216 in the method `getFolderSize`? That's where you get your null ref.

Comment: in the 216 line there is this `for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {`

Answer (score 2):

/sdcard/Pictures should be existing by default for normal android phones (however you should also make sure this folder does exist before you use it). But the most possible reason might be the permission issue.

Have you required the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? User might be able to **force this permission request** in developer settings. This option will make the system check the application if it has granted the "READ" permission during installation. If you haven't done so, you cannot open the file in sdcard.

Check the official document description of this permission:

```
public static final String READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Added in API level 16
Allows an application to read from external storage.

Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted this permission.

This permission is enforced starting in API level 19. Before API level 19, this permission is not enforced and all apps still have access to read from external storage. You can test your app with the permission enforced by enabling Protect USB storage under Developer options in the Settings app on a device running Android 4.1 or higher.

Also starting in API level 19, this permission is not required to read/write files in your application-specific directories returned by getExternalFilesDir(String) and getExternalCacheDir().

Note: If both your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion values are set to 3 or lower, the system implicitly grants your app this permission. If you don't need this permission, be sure your targetSdkVersion is 4 or higher.

---

And I am not sure if Lg optimus L9 P760 has a removable SDCARD, if so, that is also another possibility.

Comment: I think could be the problem because i forgot that permission.. I wrote only `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` but not the READ permissions... I have to try now..

Answer (score 0):

You've sort of answered your own question. The directory doesn't exist and so trying to list files on it causes a `NullPointerException`.

You should first verify that it exists like so:

```
File pictures = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Pictures/");
if (pictures.exists()) 
    float picturesize=getFolderSize(pictures)/(1024f*1024f);
```

Comment: yeah you're right.. this is the best thing to do..i forgot this control

Comment: Since API level 8 `DIRECTORY_PICTURES` is available - maybe better to use that instead of hardcoding the String. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_PICTURES